# eliminar notacion cientifica en un archivo csv

Tags: php, postgresql

tengo un problema, al generar un archivo .csv con php al abrirlo en excel un campo que tengo denominado como cedula de ubicacion que tiene mas de 15 caracteres numericos al abrirlo lo cambia a esta notacion

la idea es que al abrir el excel  debe de mostrarme este dato: "101210010000001" pero el excel lo cambia de esta manera: "1,0121E+14"

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el problema es del Excel, no del archivo CSV

Comment: Metelos entre comillas dobles ... es un problema de formato...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema de formato. Dado que el formato por defecto es el `General`, te lo cambia a notación científica.

Para solucionarlo con esa fila, y con todas las demás, convendría :

- <kbd>1</kbd> seleccionar esa columna completa
- <kbd>2</kbd> en el menú superior ir a `Formato / Celdas`
- <kbd>3</kbd>en la ventana que se abrirá seleccionar la pestaña `Número` si no está selecciona ya
- <kbd>4</kbd>luego, en `Categoría`, seleccionar `Número`.
- <kbd>5</kbd>establecer las `posiciones decimales` a `0`
- <kbd>6</kbd>asegurarse que la casilla `Usar separador de miles` **no esté marcada**.
- <kbd>7</kbd>finalmente, pulsar en `Aceptar`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Edición aclarando [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148471/eliminar-notacion-cientifica-en-un-archivo-csv/148496?noredirect=1#comment278607_148496):

Este problema es debido al formato, no al tamaño de la celda.

Aquí se ha agrandado el tamaño de la celda, dejando el formato establecido en `General`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí establecemos el formato a `Numero`, aplicando lo dicho más arriba en la respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hay problema de tamaño espacial, Excel no convierte a notación científica, sino que muestra `#`...  hasta que se amplía el tamaño de la columna.

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias funciono a la perfección +1

Comment: @AngelGutierrez Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: puede que esto funcione.. pero agrandando la celda no anda tambien??? ;)

Comment: @gbianchi no. Si así fuera, Excel no convertiría a notación científica, sino que mostraría el caracter `#` hasta que la celda se amplíe.

Comment: si son numeros, lo pasa a cientifica.. probalo ;).. si es una cadena.. a #####

Comment: @gbianchi correcto, no hay contradicción en lo que digo. El OP dice estar manejando caracteres numéricos, no cadenas. Las imágenes que muestro en la edición de la respuesta están basadas en números. Si fueran cadenas, no los pasa a nada, los muestra tal cual.

Comment: nunca dije lo contrario.. ;)

Comment: @gbianchi si es una cadena, no muestra `#` cuando se reduce el espacio. Acabo de probarlo.